# How to add jar files in pyspark anaconda?

Tags: pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf=SparkConf().setAppName("2048roject").setMaster("local[*]")\
     .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "80g").set("spark.executor.memory", "5g").set("spark.driver.memory", "60g")
sc=SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
dfv = sc.textFile("./part-001*.gz")
```

I have install pyspark thru anaconda and I can import pyspark in anaconda python. But I don't know how to add jar files in `conf`.

I tried

```
conf=SparkConf().setAppName("2048roject").setMaster("local[*]")\
     .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "80g").set("spark.executor.memory", "5g").set("spark.driver.memory", "60g").set('spark.jars.packages','file:///XXX,jar')
```

but it doesn't work.
Any proper way to add jar file here ?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) say:

> spark.jars.packages: Comma-separated list of Maven coordinates of jars to include on the driver and executor classpaths. The coordinates should be groupId:artifactId:version. If spark.jars.ivySettings is given artifacts will be resolved according to the configuration in the file, otherwise artifacts will be searched for in the local maven repo, then maven central and finally any additional remote repositories given by the command-line option --repositories. For more details, see Advanced Dependency Management.

Instead, you should simply use `spark.jars`:

> spark.jars: Comma-separated list of jars to include on the driver and executor classpaths. Globs are allowed.

So:

```
conf=SparkConf().setAppName("2048roject").setMaster("local[*]")\
     .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "80g").set("spark.executor.memory", "5g").set("spark.driver.memory", "60g").set('spark.jars.files','file:///XXX.jar')
```